# First use of 'demonic invasion of Earth' in science fiction or fantasy, as opposed to mythology

Tags: history-of, demons

Demonic invasions are a popular trope used in video games, comics, manga, anime, etc. This first appeared in mythology of course.

So I've been meaning to find out when this trope was first used in science fiction or fantasy.

Can you guys please help me with this?

Comment: One example is 1982 *The Elfstones of Shannara* by Terry Brooks. I’d be surprised if that’s the earliest.

Comment: Also the Cthulhu mythos of HP Lovecraft from around the 1920s is at least similar to this trope.

Comment: It's hard to collectively write a timeline, and there would be issues about what does and doesn't fit; it would be better to ask about the _first_ appearance of the idea, though you would have to distinguish it from the biblical concept of Armageddon.

Comment: @StarDustLad - I removed the [story-identification] tag, as it's only supposed to be used when looking for a specific story you've already been exposed to in some fashion. It isn't used when looking for the earliest example of a given trope.

Comment: How can this be answered? Demons have a religious/mythological origin and have merely been appropriated in science fiction and fantasy. If someone found an early story that included a demon but no other fictional elements, would it be eligible? What elements of fantasy or science fiction would be needed to make the story qualify?

Answer (score 6):

To make this focused, we could say that "demons" has to mean the creatures from popular Christian mythology, and that the story where they appear is doing something other than a straight portrayal of that tradition. If not for this, then we're going back to the book of Revelation or earlier, and dealing with stories that *have demons* but aren't really fantasy or science fiction. There has to be some extra fantastical or science-fictional element. Also, I wouldn't count a story which says "demon" but just treats that as a synonym for "monster", like some of the horror stories by Lovecraft and friends.

The earliest example I know is an 1887 story "Le Horla" by Guy de Maupassant featuring invisible spirits who come from outer space, and possess people as part of their potential conquest of the planet. They are said to be the same creatures that gave rise to our stories of supernatural beings such as fairies; he does not say "demons", but perhaps we can take that as implied, given the possession angle.

If this does *not* count, then the next best might be C. S. Lewis's *Out of the Silent Planet* (1938), which presents a science fictional reskinning of Christian cosmology. In particular, our Earth is already conquered by demons (the "dark eldila"), who are incorporeal evil aliens, ruled by Satan ("the Bent Oyarsa"). Because their invasion was successful in the deep past, we don't see hordes of demons pouring across the landscape, and they're also more subtle in their malevolence.

Comment: Please propose a single concrete answer, rather than surveying a bunch of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "aliens who might have been the base for demon myths", [The Mightiest Machine](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?318041) by John W. Campbell ([originally serialized in 5 parts in Astounding Stories magazine from December 1934 to April 1935](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mightiest_Machine)) might be a contender.

Admittedly they have been driven from earth to another universe instead of invading earth, but the very evil alien race of Teff-Hellani does look like the devil, with horns and clubbed feet and everything and are thought to be by the Terran explorers who encounter them (and wipe them out with advanced weapons, because this is after all a John W. Campbell story) to be the base of myths of demons and devils.

Answer (score 1):

[Black Easter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2352) 1968 by James Blish involves an actual invasion of Judeo-Christian demons, and is the first such SF story I know of. *The Mightiest Machine* doesn't seem to me to fully fit that description. *Out of the Silent Planet* does not really involve an invasion, in my view, rather the demons (dark eldils) are all over the Earth and have been for millennia.